# Display results from object in JSX

Tags: javascript, reactjs, object, react-native

I am trying to display results from an object in JSX. I have a api request in the componentWillMount() method. This returns an object like this

```
Object {Name: "testname", Surname: "testsurname", IdNumber: "9008067986743", Email: "test@gmail.com", Mobile: "+263 73 359 432"}
```

Now I need to display for eg. the Email in the JSX below

```
  render(){
  return (
    <Container>
      <Header />
      <Content>
        <Card>  
          <CardItem>             
            <Left>
              <Thumbnail source={{uri: 'https://openclipart.org/image/2400px/svg_to_png/177482/ProfilePlaceholderSuit.png'}} />
              <Body>
                <Text>NEED EMAIL HERE</Text>
              </Body>
            </Left>
          </CardItem>
        </Card>            
      </Content>
    </Container>
  );
}
```

Please assist me with this, thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After your API call, just put the response to the state, and plot it in your render method

```
constructor(props){
   super(props);
   this.state = { myObject: {} };
}

componentDidMount(){
  //your API request here
  .then(response => response.json().then(result => {
     this.setState({ myObject: result });
  }))
  .catch((err) => { throw err; });
}

render(){
  return (
    <Container>
      <Header />
      <Content>
        <Card>  
          <CardItem>             
            <Left>
              <Thumbnail source={{uri: 'https://openclipart.org/image/2400px/svg_to_png/177482/ProfilePlaceholderSuit.png'}} />
              <Body>
                <Text>Email:</Text>
                <Text>{this.state.myObject.Email}</Text>
                <Text>Name:</Text>
                <Text>{this.state.myObject.Name}</Text>
                <Text>Surname:</Text>
                <Text>{this.state.myObject.Surname}</Text>
                <Text>ID Number:</Text>
                <Text>{this.state.myObject.IdNumber}</Text>
              </Body>
            </Left>
          </CardItem>
        </Card>            
      </Content>
    </Container>
  );
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I have tried this but it doesn't display any results. It's just leaves the fields in the JSX blank. I think it's trying to display the results before any data is available

Comment: This works, marked as correct, just also needed to make sure the incoming data was in the correct format

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the data in your state initially to null, call API in componentWillMount and update state with the API response.

In following code initially state would be null so render function would return null. Now after API promise is completed your state would be updated by `setState` and your `render function` would be called again displaying your API data.

```
class Example extends React.Component {
  state = {
    data: null
  }

  componentWillMount () {
    fetch(//your endpoint)
    .then((data) => {
      this.setState({data})
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.warn(error);
    })
  }

  render () {
    if (!this.state.data) return null;
    return (
      <div>
        <span>{this.state.data.email}</span>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
let requestedObject = {Name: "testname", Surname: "testsurname", IdNumber: "9008067986743", Email: "test@gmail.com", Mobile: "+263 73 359 432"}   

 render(){
      return (
        <Container>
          <Header />
          <Content>
            <Card>  
              <CardItem>             
                <Left>
                  <Thumbnail source={{uri: 'https://openclipart.org/image/2400px/svg_to_png/177482/ProfilePlaceholderSuit.png'}} />
                  <Body>
                    <Text>{ requestedObject.email }</Text>
                  </Body>
                </Left>
              </CardItem>
            </Card>            
          </Content>
        </Container>
      );
    }
```

Whenever you write javascript in JSX(between tags like `<Text> </Text>`) you need to put that javascript code in curly braces.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you have your object in `this.props.info`. You can do:

```
      render(){
        const { Email, Surname, Name } = this.props.info;
          return (
            <Container>
              <Header />
              <Content>
                <Card>  
                  <CardItem>             
                    <Left>
                      <Thumbnail source={{uri: 'https://openclipart.org/image/2400px/svg_to_png/177482/ProfilePlaceholderSuit.png'}} />
                      <Body>
                        <Text>NEED EMAIL HERE</Text>
                        <Text>{Name}</Text>
                        <Text>{Surname}</Text>
                        <Text>{Email}</Text>
                      </Body>
                    </Left>
                  </CardItem>
                </Card>            
              </Content>
            </Container>
          );
        }
```